# Can such a set be simply connected?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let $U$ be an open subset of $\R^2$ such that the point $(0,0)$ is on the boundary of $U$. Let $f\colon[0,1]\to\R^2$ be the path that starts at $(0,0)$ and moves with a (say) constant speed, first horizontally right to $(2,0)$, then horizontally left to $(1,0)$, and finally goes counterclockwise twice over the unit circle. Let $g\colon[0,1]\to\R^2$ be another continuous path that also starts at $(0,0)$ and such that $g(t)\in U$ for all $t\in(0,1]$ and $|g(t)-f(t)|<1/16$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm.

Can then the set $U$ be simply connected?

Comment: If I understand correctly, $g(t)$ should have a self-intersection $g(a)=g(b)$ for some $0<a<b\le1$, so that $g|_{[a,b]}$ is a non contractible closed loop in $\mathbb R^2\setminus (0,0)$,  so in $U$ neither.

Comment: @PietroMajer : Thank you for your comment. Can you detail the self-intersection statement, preferably in a formal answer, so that I could accept it?

Comment: Nice question. What happens if we change the condition from <1/16 to <1/4 or <1/2? I think U can be simply connected if the condition is <1/2+epsilon. But maybe it also works for a stricter condition...?

Comment: @jcsahnwaldtReinstateMonica : Thank you for your comment. Yes, it looks like one can go from $1/16$ up to $1/2$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Do you assume that $g$ is a loop?

Comment: @GaelMeigniez : No, $g$ does not have to be a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I_0$ be the interval where $f$ is a horizontal motion, and let $I_1$ the interval where it is a circular motion. So up to reparametrisation (and adopting complex notation) $I_0=[-3,0]$  and $I_1=[0,4\pi]$, and $f(t)=\min(t+3,1-t)$ in $I_0$ and $f(t)=e^{it}$ in $I_1$.

Since $|g(3\pi/2)+i|<1/16$ and $|g(5\pi/2)-i|<1/16$ by connection there are points $t_0\in I_0$ and $ 3\pi/2< t_1 < 5\pi/2$ such that $g(t_1)=g(t_0)$ **(*)**.

This means that $g$ restricts to a closed arc on $[t_0,t_1]$, which is  still $1/16$ close, up to reparametrisation, to the loop $f|[-2,2\pi]$, which is non contractible in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore so is the loop $g_{|[t_0,t_1]}$, and a fortiori in $U\subset  \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore $U$ is not simply connected.

**(*)** This can be seen geometrically as a consequence of the  Jordan curve theorem (note  that $g(I_0)$, as any image of a continuous curve, contains a simple curve with the same endpoints, and this can be enlarged to a simple closed curve bounding  a domain containing $g(3\pi/2)$ and not $g(5\pi/2)$. Otherwise, without bothering about injectivity: $g_{|I_0}$ can be extended to a closed loop $\gamma$, juxtaposing to it an arc far from $g(I_1)$,  and such that $\text{ind}(\gamma,g(3\pi/2))=-1$ and $\text{ind}(\gamma,g(5\pi/2))=0$, which implies that $g_{|[3\pi/2,5\pi/2]}$  must cross the curve $\gamma$ (necessarily in $g(I_0)$) otherwise $\text{ind}(\gamma,g(t))$ would remain constant for $3\pi/2\le t \le 5\pi/2$